# Preview and edit links causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS if not logged in

Tags: login

Quirky thing that I've noticed while working on a client's CMS. When I send them preview links in the format of `https://campaigns.redacted.com/?sc_itemid=%7B0EA000BF-8F51-482C-9F67-6AE044B64F2F%7D&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en&sc_site=redacted` and they try to open that URL **when not already logged into Sitecore**, even in Incognito mode they keep getting `campaigns.redacted.com redirected you too many times.` Indeed, the status bar of the browser (Chrome) starts going crazy and in Fiddler I just see a constant array of tunnels to campaigns.redacted.com. The URL in the browser after Chrome gives up is:

```
https://campaigns.redacted.com/sitecore/login?sc_itemid=%7B0EA000BF-8F51-482C-9F67-6AE044B64F2F%7D&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en&sc_site=redacted&returnUrl=%2525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Fsc_itemid%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525257B0EA000BF-8F51-482C-9F67-6AE044B64F2F%252525252525252525252525252525252525257D%25252525252525252525252525252525252526sc_mode%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Dpreview%25252525252525252525252525252525252526sc_lang%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Den%25252525252525252525252525252525252526sc_site%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Dredacted
```

I've tried disabling our custom IIS rewrite rules and also removing the `requireSSL` property on the `httpCookies` node of web.config, and this has brought about no changes. Their instance is running Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115. Other browsers seem to give similar results.

**EDIT**: After running the resulting URL provided through a URL decoder, it looks like this. Not sure if this is relevant or if you can see something wrong with how this URL is structured?

```
https://campaigns.redacted.com/sitecore/login?sc_itemid={0EA000BF-8F51-482C-9F67-6AE044B64F2F}&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en&sc_site=redacted&returnUrl=/?sc_itemid={0EA000BF-8F51-482C-9F67-6AE044B64F2F}&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en&sc_site=redacted
```